# Private variable not staying private in JS module

Tags: javascript

After reading the following article,
 http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-module-pattern/
I have decided to start implementing modules in my JS.

Unfortunately, the module I am using does not seem to be keeping the private variable private,

```
var popoverOptionsModule = (function() {
var _stopAskingList = [];

var addToStopAskingList = function(itemToAdd) {
    if (_stopAskingList.indexOf(itemToAdd) === -1){
      _stopAskingList.push(itemToAdd);
    }
}

var getStopAskingList = function() {
    return _stopAskingList;
}


return {
    addToStopAskingList: addToStopAskingList,
    getStopAskingList: getStopAskingList,
};
})();

popoverOptionsModule._stopAskingList = 4;
console.log(popoverOptionsModule._stopAskingList);
```

As you can see, I am able to change the value of 
popoverOptionsModule._stopAskingList and log the update to the console... I thought this was not supposed to happen. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `console.log(popoverOptionsModule.getStopAskingList())`. This is the reason why you implemented a getter function in the first place.

Comment: by doing `popoverOptionsModule._stopAskingList = 4;` you are creating a new property on the object so of course you can console.log it out. Remove that line and it will log undefined as expected.

Comment: I don't see the reason why this was downvoted; it is very clear the problem the poster is experiencing, and it is also not a concept that is immediately obvious without being exposed to it.  Yes, most people who work with JavaScript frequently have been exposed to it, but asking questions about things you haven't been exposed to is perfectly relevant here.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS is completely dynamically typed, so when you have the line

```
popoverOptionsModule._stopAskingList = 4;
```

You've just created this variable and assigned it a value, hence why the next line succeeds.  If you didn't have this line, then the subsequent console.log would report undefined.  This code would work too

```
popoverOptionsModule._abc = 4;
console.log(popoverOptionsModule._abc);
```

Remember that this isn't actually a private variable in the same way that OO languages implement protection levels, rather it's just an API pattern that attempts to hide it from the caller.